# How to watch dynamic Vuex store change in the Vue component?

Tags: vuejs2, nuxt.js, vuex, watch

I need to watch Vuex store. The problem is that the store is dynamic store. As I know I can watch Vuex store as string but how to do it with dynamic store which name is in the variable?

I found this code:

```js
watch: {
    '$store.state.local_store.list_of_data':{
        handler(){
            console.log("value changeing in party sales entry");
        },
    deep:true
    }
},
```

But I have a store which is called like this

```js
this.$store.dispatch(`${this.storeName}/updateNewShare`, this.newShareToken);
```

where `this.storeName` is the name of the dynamic module. I can not use variables in watcher string. Can I?

Comment: I don't think that Vue2 can watch this dynamically. And anyway, I think that this one should be on the Vuex side, so maybe try to look into this one: https://vuex.vuejs.org/api/#watch

Comment: Ok thanks. May be I dont need it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use the watch API from your mounted or created lifecycle.

```
mounted() {
  store.watch(()=>`${this.storeName}/updateNewShare`, value=>{})
}
```